# How to show display and hide text instead of using alert in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is javascript for up and down vote click function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //####### on page load, retrive votes for each content
    $.each( $('.voting_wrapper'), function(){

        //retrive unique id from this voting_wrapper element
        var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");

        //prepare post content
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};

        //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
        $.post('vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {

                //retrive votes from server, replace each vote count text
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up); 
                $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(response.vote_down);
            },'json');
    });

    //####### on button click, get user vote and send it to vote_process.php using jQuery $.post().
    $(".voting_wrapper .voting_btn").click(function (e) {

        //get class name (down_button / up_button) of clicked element
        var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');

        //get unique ID from voted parent element
        var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id"); 

        if(clicked_button==='down_button') //user disliked the content
        {
            //prepare post content
            post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'down'};

            //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //replace vote down count text with new values
                $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(data);

                //thank user for the dislike
                alert("Thanks! Each Vote Counts, Even Dislikes!");

            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert user about the HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }
        else if(clicked_button==='up_button') //user liked the content
        {
            //prepare post content
            post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};

            //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //replace vote up count text with new values
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);

                //thank user for liking the content
                alert("Thanks! For Liking This Content.");
            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert user about the HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }

    });
//end 

});
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <h3><img src="9780143332497.jpg" alt="">
        <!-- voting markup -->
        <div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes">0</span>
            </div>
                    </div>
        <!-- voting markup end -->
    </h3>

    </div>
```

When click the button, it shows the text as alert box,

May i know, how to shows text and hide like animate,

I need when i click the button, it shows "you voted" and after that it hide.

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div with an id and put it where you want to show the text. Then you can replace your alert statement with something like

`$('#myDiv').text('My Text!');`

or

`$('#myDiv').innerHtml('<span>My Text!</span>');`

Comment: Thanks,. And may i know for hide after some 200ms?

Comment: how to edit my code?.. i am newbie in jquery.. thanks

Comment: Like this, for example:

*setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000);* You should also take a look at alertify.js: http://alertifyjs.com/

Comment: can you please see my updated post, from that how to achieve this?.. I am struggling where i can add your code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the Button is clicked, create a div container and show it.
Then wait 2000ms and then fade it out!

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
        var myAlert = $('<div />').addClass("alert alert-success").html("test");
        $("body").append(myAlert);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(myAlert).fadeOut();
        },2000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.. but how to do with my existing source code?

Comment: just replace it with your  `alert("Thanks! For Liking This Content.");`

Answer (score -1):

What you want to use is called modal/popup/dialog. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) you have an example of using modal in bootstrap. All you need to do it to replace `alert()` in your code with properly used modal window.